# PHP Error: unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

I get **syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING** in my echo.
Can't figure out what is causing it. Any thoughts?

```
    else{ echo ('<div id="cont-load"><div class="body-container"><div id="logo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 158.172 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMixYMid meet"><path d=""></path></svg></div><div id="promo" class="animate"></div>

<form action="" method="post" id="fes-form" class="animate" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="hidden" name="fes-name" class="fes-input" value=" '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].' ">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0">
    <input type="hidden" name="fes-group" value="3">

    <div id="notification-container"><div id="notification">'.$mkd01.'<div id="secondary">'.$mkd04.'</div></div></div>

    <div id="composite-field"><input type="email" id="fes-email" name="fes-email" class="fes-input animate" value=" '.($_COOKIE['HL'])' " placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"><button type="submit" id="fes-submit" class="fes-submit animate" value="" disabled></button></div>    

</form>

<!-- .body-container --></div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="body-container"><!-- .body-container -->
    <div id="footer-indent" class="animate">
        <div id="info">
            <div id="copyright">&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> — <span></span></div>
            <div id="page-no">EFWP101</div>     
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .body-container --></div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function() { $("#circle-loader").fadeOut(300); $("#cont-load").fadeIn(800); }); </script>

<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #cont-load --></div>');
```

Comment: And on which line do you get the error? Probably here: `'.($_COOKIE['HL'])'` Where is the other concatenation dot?

Comment: The `()` brackets are redundant around that cookie reference, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a dot `.` after `$_COOKIE['HL']` on this line:

```
'
<div id="composite-field"><input type="email" id="fes-email" name="fes-email" class="fes-input animate" value=" '.($_COOKIE['HL'])' " placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"><button type="submit" id="fes-submit" class="fes-submit animate" value="" disabled></button></div>
```

An "unexpected string" error generally means you've got a `'string'` bumped up against something that it shouldn't be next to. In this case, a variable when there should be a concatenating dot.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that